# Decreasing Performance of Jena function "ResultSetFactory.copyResults()"

Tags: performance, sparql, jena, owl

I am querying my ontology using SPARQL, but I observe a decreasing performance the more queries I request, the worse it gets. At the beginning the PC needs about 150ms to process the query, the 30. query needs 670ms and the 100. query needs over 7 seconds! 
It is depending on the query and/or ontology, but until now, I could find it in every ontology.

The line "ResultSetRewindable r = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results);" is responsible for the time leak, but also work arounds by avoiding the line lead to similar behaviour.

I used the pizza ontology (https://ontohub.org/pizza/pizza.owl) and the following code. Additionally, I used the Jena version 2.13.

Has anybody an idea how to fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InterruptedException{
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    String OWLPath = "pizza.owl";
    String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> PREFIX pz: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE {     ?b owl:someValuesFrom pz:MozzarellaTopping. ?x rdfs:subClassOf ?b.      ?x rdfs:subClassOf* pz:Pizza.}";
    for(int j=0; j<100;j++){
    double starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(OWLPath);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + OWLPath + " not found");
        }
        model.read(in, "");

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

        double time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ResultSetRewindable r = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results);
        double time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();  

        ResultSetFormatter.out(ps, r, query);
        String queryOutput = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
        String[] resultText = queryOutput.split("\n");  
        for(int i=0; i<resultText.length;i++){
            System.out.println(resultText[i]);
        }
    double endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time: "+ (endtime-starttime) +"     Time for ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results): "+ (time2-time1));
    }
 }
```

Comment: And I don't understand why you use such an old version of Jena. Can you tell me why?

Comment: By the way, you should always close the streams!

Comment: And do you print it in an IDE or to the command line? Otherwise, check the behavior without printing it. But note, printing iterates over the resultset, thus, you should also iterate over it but don't do anything.

Comment: @Median: I tried it on different computer (Mac and Windows) with the same behaviour. E.g. _Time: 927.0 Time for ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results): 901.0_
Which version do you use?

Comment: @AKSW: I print at the IDE but as you see above it does not matter. For me the 2.13. version was the most stable, I never had trouble with it, until now and newer version do not have no features I need.

Comment: I removed my comments, the OntModelSpec I used for model was rather none. This is why it was it executed fast.

Comment: @2Application Have you tried to increase the heap size?

Comment: Yeah, the heap size has no influence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a simple error. The problem is that the model is not cleaned up, every time the ontology is read, the model size increases. 
The model can cleaned up with:

```
model.removeAll();
```

or the line

```
model.read(in, "");
```

can be replaces by

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read(in, "");
```

It will work without any problem in version 2.13 and 3.3.0. Additionally, the required time decreased by the factor 5, so the performance is better and it runs stable. The second version is only slightly better than the first one.